# Electron App, Laravel API

Tags: php, electron

**My Scenario**

I'm building an app in [electron](https://electronjs.org) and using Laravel as an API for authenticating users / other functionality. I'm not sure however if I need to worry about security in the same way. The reason i say this is because laravel implements a CSRF (Cross Site Request Forgery) protection, But my electron app isn't a site essentially, its an app. And if I was to worry about CSRF just as an example. How would i go about creating a CSRF token using plain JS.

**My Question**

Do I need to worry about things like CSRF (Or anything like this) when using software like electron. If so how would i go about making a CSRF token in JS to meet these needs.

**More Information**

You can use in the app, but everywhere i look its [not advised to](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/176978/is-there-a-way-to-develop-desktop-software-using-php) since it runs on windows but you need an apache server to run PHP functions and scripts else things start to get much more complex than need be. So I have to build the app using JS/VueJs etc. Thats why im using a hosted laravel server as my API (And also because im really familiar with Laravel).

Comment: I am facing a similar issue. Did you manage to find a solution to this?

Comment: @jjaulimsing i ran across a few things that said to use laravel passport, but i never went through with it, you should check it out https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/passport

Comment: All notes I read recommends the same but was hoping there'd be a simpler alternative. I ended implementing the module, thanks for confirming.

Comment: Laravel Sanctum solves this problem now https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/sanctum

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Laravel for the API, then you don't have to worry about CSRF tokens like mentioned in the comments you can use [Laravel passport](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/passport) or the new [Laravel Sanctum](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/sanctum) but my personal favourite is using JWT tokens using a trendy package for JSON Web Token Authentication for Laravel & Lumen (9.3K stars at the time of writing) called [jwt-auth](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth) by [tymondesigns](https://github.com/tymondesigns) it is well [documented](https://jwt-auth.readthedocs.io/en/develop/) and very easy to integrate and use. You can use it to authenticate all kinds of apps that interact with the API and also has some advanced features for greater security.